# JavaScript - How to remove all instances of a string and parts of the string from another string/how to append string to form parameter on submit?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms

I have an ASPX login page that has a simple login form, with a submit shown below:

```
<input type="submit" name="LoginUser$LoginButton" value="Login" onclick="appendDomain();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;LoginUser$LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;LoginUserValidationGroup&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="LoginUser_LoginButton">
```

Upon clicking on Submit, I'm appending the domain "abc\" to the username:

```
  function appendDomain(){
                var un = $("#LoginUser_UserName").val();
                $("#LoginUser_UserName").val("abc\\"+un);
  return true;         
  }
```

The issue is, because I'm appending the "abc\" before submitting the form, the browser remembers the submitted username as "abc\testUserName"

[image]

So, if I submit again, the username gets submitted as "abc\abc\testUserName" and then "abc\abc\abc\testUserName" and so on.

Is there a better way to append the domain name to the username? If no, what would be a better way to write the `appendDomain()` function? Something that would remove convert "`abc\testUserName","testUserName","abc\abc\abc\testUserName`" etc. into "`abc\testUsername`"

Comment: Um, why don;t you check to see if it is there before appending?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is not there before adding.

```
var userName = $("#LoginUser_UserName")
var un = userName.val();
if (un.indexOf("abc\\")===-1) {
    userName.val("abc\\" + un);
}
```